# Python gives me different outputs if I add a print() later on

Tags: python

I'm super new to programming and just wanted to make something to find the approximate value of `x` for the equation `x^3 - 1 = x`. I know that `-2` is greater than `0` and `-1` is less. My thought is that if I find the average and check if it's greater or less than `0`, I can redefine `a` and `b` and repeat until I get an approximate value. I've been having a hard time getting it to act right though. For example if I run this block without the print(i), I'll get `-1.5` which would be the average, but when I put a `print(total)` within the function `equation(n)` to see if it's working right, it doesn't even show me that and just outputs `-8.881784197001252e-16`. If I put `print(i)` at the end of the `if/else` possibilities, such as this, it prints `16` and then `-8.881784197001252e-16`. I'm using PyCharm CE.

Beyond this glitch, is my logic correct? By setting the placeholder to `1` it will run the while loop. The while loop will get a new value of `n` and run the function, compare it to `0`, then reassign `a` or `b` depending on that comparison? Thanks in advance.

```
a = float(-2)
b = float(-1)
n = ((a+b)/2)
print(n)

def equation(n):

    total = float((n - n**3 - 1))

    return total

i = 1

while i != 0:
    n = ((a + b) / 2)
    if (equation(n)) > 0.0:
        a = n
        i = equation(n)
        print(i)

    else:
        b = n
        i = equation(n)
        print(i)
```

Comment: The body of the `while` loop needs to be indented.

Comment: since you're new to programming you may or may not be aware but one of the things you will discover about working with floats is that they don't always work the way you expect them to in comparison operations.. so i'm guessing you're testing for negative values but i'm unclear why you're running an infinite while loop because idk if i will ever == zero ...if you want an infinite loop just do while True

Comment: Post the code with the problem, not the working code. We can't tell what you're doing wrong based on your description.

Comment: I edited the code to the erroneous code. The loop may be infinite but I'm trying to get as close to the answer as possible. What would you recommend I use if not a float?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  If you wanted to track that down, try inserting a break statement in PyCharm and then running your code in debug mode.  That will let you step over your code as each instruction is executed and see what variable values are.  That's the easiest way to track down the issue.

Comment: [Here's some info](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window.html) on the debug interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving all of the equation `x^3 - 1 = x` to one side should give `x^3 - 1 - x = 0` or `x - x^3 + 1 = 0`.  You have a different equation in your function.

Another problem is that there is no intersection between the two equations between `x=-2` and `x=-1` (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7Bx%5E3-1,x%7D,%7Bx,-2,-1%7D%5D)).  You'll need to expand your window to `x=2` before you'll see an intersection.

Something that often happens in numerical analysis (where you'll see this type of problem) is that rather than trying to find `x` that actually makes the equation give `0`, we look for a value of `x` that produces below an acceptable level of error.  Another approach is to test for `while b - a > tol:`

If we use all of this to tweak what you've got, you'll have

```
a = float(-2)
b = float(2)
tol = 0.001

def equation(n):
    return float(n - n**3 + 1)

n = (a + b) / 2
iter = 0
while abs(equation(n) - 0) > tol and iter < 100:
    iter+=1

    if equation(n) > 0.0:
        a = n
    else:
        b = n

    n = (a + b) / 2

    print(iter,a,b,equation(n))
```

---

Note: this works fine if you remove the floats and just do

```
a = -2
b = 2
#...etc
```

because python already recasts values as necessary.  Try

```
>>> type(3)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(3.5)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(float(3))
<class 'float'>
>>> type(3/5)
<class 'float'>
```

so python will store the result as a float as soon as it is necessary.

Comment: note: `type(3/5)` is only a float in python 3. Everything else you say is right though

Comment: Ah, good catch.  I remember running into that when I first tried python ages ago.  Haven't used anything but 3 in so long I forget some of the differences like that.

Comment: So am I correct in assuming that because I was running an infinite loop it somehow messed up the output?

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is the limited precision of floats. If you print `a` and `b` after a hundred iterations, you get:

```
a, b = -1.324717957244746, -1.3247179572447458
print((a + b) / 2  # -1.3247179572447458, the same as b
```

So at some point, b never changes, which is why you get an infinite loop. If we evaluate `equation` at the average of `a` and `b`, you'll get -8.881784197001252e-16, the value you were always seeing.

But this will never converge to *exactly* zero because the solution is [irrational](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3+-1+%3D+x), so even if you had infinite precision, equation would never equal zero.

The common way to resolve this issue is to avoid comparing floats:

```
if a == b               # don't do this
if abs(a - b) < epsilon      # do this, where epsilon is some small value
```

(Note: what you're describing is the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), which is slower than higher order algorithms e.g. Newton's method, which you can use since you can get the derivative)

Comment: This doesn't address OP's fundamental problem: the equality he's trying to solve doesn't match the equation in his code.

Comment: To expand on the answer you gave, though, to a computer, a lot more numbers are irrational than what we'd normally thing about.  For example, `0.1` is irrational once we try to store it as a binary fraction.

Comment: You're completely right, I didn't catch that error. I think our answers complement each other :)